# Python Issue with if statements and randint

Tags: python

Probably just overlooking something incredibly simple but i simply cannot figure out what is wrong with my code. I am not amazing so apologies if this is super simple but here is my full code. its a simple rock paper scissors programme.

```
import time
import random
#ascii art
print("")
print(" ____  ____  ____  ")
time.sleep(0.25)
print("|  _ \|  _ \/ ___| ")
time.sleep(0.25)
print("| |_) | |_) \___ \ ")
time.sleep(0.25)
print("|  _ <|  __/ ___) |")
time.sleep(0.25)
print("|_| \_\_|   |____/ ")
print("")
#ascii art

guess = input("Guess either rock, paper or scissors: ")

if guess in ["rock", "Rock"]:
    print("You Chose Rock!")
elif guess in ["paper", "Paper"]:
    print("You Chose Paper!")
elif guess in ["scissors", "Scissors"]:
    print("You Chose Scissors!")
else:
    print("That isnt an option!")

print("")

answer = random.ranint(1, 3)

if answer == 1:
    if guess in ["rock", "Rock"]:
        print("You Tied!")
        print("Try again!")
        print("")
        print("""
        _______
        ---'   ____)
              (_____)
              (_____)
               (____)
        ---.__(___)
        """)
        time.sleep(9999)
    elif guess in ["Paper", "paper"]:
        print("You Won! GG!")
        print("")
        print("""
        _______
        ---'   ____)
              (_____)
              (_____)
               (____)
        ---.__(___)
        """)
        time.sleep(9999)
    elif guess in ["scissors", "Scissors"]:
        print("You lost :(")
        print("Try again!")
        print("")
        print("""
        _______
        ---'   ____)
              (_____)
              (_____)
               (____)
        ---.__(___)
        """)
        time.sleep(9999)
elif answer == 2:
    if guess in ["rock", "Rock"]:
        print("You Lost!")
        print("Try again!")
        print("")
        print("""
             _______
        ---'    ____)____
                   ______)
                  _______)
                 _______)
        ---.__________)
        """)
        time.sleep(9999)
    elif guess in ["Paper", "paper"]:
        print("You Tied!")
        print("Try again!")
        print("")
        print("""
             _______
        ---'    ____)____
                   ______)
                  _______)
                 _______)
        ---.__________)
        """)
        time.sleep(9999)
    elif guess in ["scissors", "Scissors"]:
        print("You Won! GG!")
        print("")
        print("""
             _______
        ---'    ____)____
                   ______)
                  _______)
                 _______)
        ---.__________)
        """)
        time.sleep(9999)
elif answer == 3:
    if guess in ["rock", "Rock"]:
        print("You Won! GG!")
        print("")
        print("""
            _______
        ---'   ____)____
                  ______)
               __________)
              (____)
        ---.__(___)
        """)
        time.sleep(9999)
    elif guess in ["Paper", "paper"]:
        print("You Lost :(")
        print("Try again!")
        print("")
        print("""
            _______
        ---'   ____)____
                  ______)
               __________)
              (____)
        ---.__(___)
        """)
        time.sleep(9999)
    elif guess in ["scissors", "Scissors"]:
        print("You Tied!")
        print("Try again!")
        print("")
        print("""
            _______
        ---'   ____)____
                  ______)
               __________)
              (____)
        ---.__(___)
        """)
        time.sleep(9999)
```

The code works up until the input, where it simply crashes. I am not sure how to debug my code or get the logs without installing a crapton of useless plugins into my code or my pc.
any help is appreciated
thanks!

Comment: "where it simply crashes" -> Please provide the traceback of your errors

Comment: You should do guess.lower() == 'rock'. Much better than ROCK getting missed out. Not the solution but an option to address all your if statements

Comment: `random.ranint(1, 3)`  ... missing a `d`

Comment: I recommend creating a list `rps = ['rock','paper','scissor']` Then do `answer=random.randint(0,2). Then check if `rsp[ answer ] == guess.lower()`, you win else you fail. You can even print `f'You Chose {guess} and Computer chose { rps[ answer ] }`

Comment: Also try to provide shortest reproducible code sample next time instead of full program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in `answer = random.ranint(1, 3)`
it should be a
`answer = random.randint(1, 3)`

Comment: Can't tell you if there's more errors, cause you haven't introduced the error trace

Comment: Yep, it should work after this improvement